# Webpack is not compiling

Tags: reactjs, webpack

With my React-Django project I'm running into an issue with Webpack. It's not generating the compiled file (main.js) like I expected and I'm not sure what the problem is. The file tree looks as follows:

```
|-- __init__.py
|-- admin.py
|-- apps.py
|-- migrations
|   -- __init__.py
|-- models.py
|-- package-lock.json
|-- package.json
|-- src
|   |-- components
|   |   -- App.js
|   -- index.js
|-- static
|   -- frontend
|-- templates
|   -- frontend
|       -- index.html
|-- tests.py
|-- urls.py
|-- views.py
|-- webpack.config.js
```

I configured webpack like this:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    "./src/index.js"
  ],
  output: {
    filename: "main.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'static', 'frontend')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

I'm running my react project with `npm run dev`, where the dev script is `"dev": "webpack serve --mode development`. This package.json looks as follows:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack serve --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.13",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.2.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "webpack": "^5.24.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.5.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  }
}
```

I've been looking for the mistake for a couple of hours now so I hope someone can help me out here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start webpack with webpack dev server (which you do with `webpack serve`),  it compiles everything into memory and serve from there. If you want to emit files you, probably don't need dev server, so just startgin `webpack watch` would be sufficient. If you need dev server and want to emit files, you can set it with this [`writeToDisk`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverwritetodisk-) option